# jQuery each function is not working and unable to create json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying create a json string. i have to get all element value from html with class and name. I am using jQuery

**HTML**

```
<div id="PackageBuilder-AddPax-Main">   
    <div class="PackageBuilder-AddPax">
        <div>   
            <input type="text" name="input1" value="A1">
            <div class="HotelSearchFrom-div-input2">
                <input type="text" name="input2" value="1">
                <input type="text" name="input2" value="2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PackageBuilder-AddPax">
        <div>   
            <input type="text" name="input1" value="A2">
            <div class="HotelSearchFrom-div-input2">
                <input type="text" name="input2" value="3">
                <input type="text" name="input2" value="4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PackageBuilder-AddPax">
        <div>   
            <input type="text" name="input1" value="A3">
            <div class="HotelSearchFrom-div-input2">
                <input type="text" name="input2" value="5">
                <input type="text" name="input2" value="6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="Make_String()">
```

**I have to make string like this but i am not be able to make it.**

```
[{"Input1":A1,"Input2":[1,2]},{"Input1":A2,"Input2":[3,4]},{"Input1":A3,"Input2":[5,6]}]
```

**Below Code i am using**

```
function Make_String(){
    var RoomGuests = [];
    var j = 0;
    $('#PackageBuilder-AddPax-Main').find('[name="input1"]').each(function(i){
        var NoOfAdults_Val = $('[name="input1"]').val()    
        var input2array = [];
        $('#HotelSearchFrom-div-input2').find('[name="input2"]').each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
            input2array.push($(this).val());
        });
        RoomGuests[j] = [];
        RoomGuests[j]['Input1'] = NoOfAdults_Val;
        RoomGuests[j]['Input2'] = input2array;
        j++
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you are messing up on line 5 and 7. Please provide more details on what is wrong

Comment: where in jquery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with jQuery each() and map().

**each() Method**

```
function Make_String() {
    array = [];

    $('.PackageBuilder-AddPax').each(function(i,e) {
        $(this).find('.HotelSearchFrom-div-input2').each(function(i,e) {
            inputarray2 = [];
            $(this).find('[name="input2"]').each(function(i,e) {
                inputarray2.push($(e).val());
            })
        })

        str = {
            'Input1': $(this).find('[name="input1"]').val(),
            'Input2': inputarray2
        }
        array.push(str);
    });

    console.log(array);
    var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(array);
    console.log(jsonstring);
}
```

OR

**map() Method**

```
function Make_String() {
    var array = $('.PackageBuilder-AddPax').map(function() {
        return {
            'Input1': $(this).find('[name="input1"]').val(),
            'Input2': $(this).find('[name="input2"]').map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get()
        }
    }).get();
    console.log(array);
    var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(array);
    console.log(jsonstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to build an object in the required format and then run that through `JSON.stringify`. To build the object you can use `map()`, like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var obj = $('.PackageBuilder-AddPax').map(function() {
        return {
            'Input1': $(this).find('[name="input1"]').val(),
            'Input2': $(this).find('[name="input2"]').map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get()
        }
    }).get();
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(json);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/avjqy5u0/)

Note that I amended the click handler so that it's attached using unobtrusive javascript, as `on*` event attributes are very outdated and should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Make_String() {
    var final = {};
    $('.PackageBuilder-AddPax').each(function() {
    $input = $(this).find($('[name="input2"]'));
    var obj = {};
    var arr = [];
    $input.each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    })
   final[$(this).find($('[name="input1"]')).val()] = arr;
   })
   console.log(final)
}
```

```js
function Make_String() {
  var final = [];
  $('.PackageBuilder-AddPax').each(function() {
    $input = $(this).find($('[name="input2"]'));
    var obj = {};
    var arr = [];
    $input.each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).val());

    })
    obj.input1 = $(this).find($('[name="input1"]')).val();
    obj.input2 = arr;
    final.push(obj);
  })
  console.log(final)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PackageBuilder-AddPax-Main">
  <div class="PackageBuilder-AddPax">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="input1" value="A1">
      <div class="HotelSearchFrom-div-input2">
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="1">
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="PackageBuilder-AddPax">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="input1" value="A2">
      <div class="HotelSearchFrom-div-input2">
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="3">
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="PackageBuilder-AddPax">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="input1" value="A3">
      <div class="HotelSearchFrom-div-input2">
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="5">
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="Make_String()">
```